# Generating Distinct Random Numbers in C++

Tags: c++

For part of a programming assignment I need to generate multiple sets of 10 numbers with a range of 1 to 50 with no repeats in each individual set, so I created the following code:

```
int Numbers[10]; //array to store the random numbers in
bool Duplicate; //variable to check or number is already used

srand(time(NULL)); //seeding the random number generator

// do while loop used to allow user to generate multiple sets 
do {

     Duplicate = false; // set check to false

     //for loop to generate a complete set of 10 random numbers
     for (int I = 0; I < 10; I++)
     {

        // do while loop used to generate random numbers until a distinct random number is generated
         do
         {
         Numbers[I] = (rand()%50) + 1; // generates a random number 1 - 50 and stores it into Numbers[I]

         // for loop used to check the other numbers in set for any repeats
         for (int J = I - 1; J > -1; J--) // works backwards from the recently generated element to element 0
              if (Numbers[I] == Numbers[J]) //checks if number is already used
                   Duplicate = true; //sets Duplicate to true to indicate there is a repeat

         } while (Duplicate); //loops until a new, distinct number is generated
     }

//at this point in the program we should have an array Numbers[] with a set of 10 unique random numbers 1 - 50

     // loop to print numbers to the screen
     for (int I = 0; I < 10; I++)
          cout << Numbers[I] << " "; // printing the element to the screen

cout << endl;
cout << "Do you want to run the program again (Y/N): "; // Asks user if they want to create another set of 10 numbers
char Answer; // used to store users answer
cin >> Answer; // stores users answer

} while (Answer == 'Y' || Answer == 'y'); // loop program if the user wants to generate another set
```

However, I seem to be having trouble with the do while loop that generates random numbers until a new, distinct number is generated.
After some testing and tinkering, I found that I have somehow created an infinite loop there and cannot figure out the problem.

Some ideas that I think may be causing the problem:
-How does the rand function change the seed and is the seed being changed to create a new pseudorandom number?
-Is my for loop to check for repeats outstepping the bounds of the array?

Any advice and hints would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I take it you're not allowed to use an (`unordered_`) `set`?

Comment: Why not fill an array from 1 - 50 and shuffle it 10 times?

Comment: So inside your do-while loop, you set Duplicate to true given certain conditions, but never gets set to false. There are also no break statements. This will create an infinite loop! You must have conditions to leave the loop.

Comment: what about setting duplicate to false somewhere near the `DO` ?

Comment: You need a shuffle, not random numbers.  Google "fisher-yates".

Comment: in the aspect of code convention - change I to i and J to j

Answer (score 2):

You're forgetting to reset `Duplicate` back to `false`. First time it is set to `true` it remains `true`, enabling an infinite `do...while` loop.

Answer (score 1):

Start with an ordered array of 1 to 50, then shuffle it via a [Fisher-Yates shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle). Then just take the first 10 numbers.

Comment: given the trouble user3179903's having, what's the chance of implementing that shuffle correctly?  It's a programming exercise - got to start somewhere....

Answer (score 1):

Notice that you don't reinitialize Duplicate to false in the beginning of your do-while loop meaning that after you have one duplicate random number - Duplicate is set to true and remains true forever therefore - your do-while loop will run forever.